# Extracting most recent day data from sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with data being inserted into from a procedure, which then I use for a Javascript chart. My problem is, I only want today's data all the time. I tried `dateadd` and `datediff` but I was still getting the same result when I did a select statement.

[image: Query]

[![Procedure][2]][2]

[image: Data][image]

Comment: Please don't paste images of code in to your questions.  There is specific mark-down in SO for formatting code snippets.

Comment: SELECT * FROM Throuhput
WHERE  YourColumn = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)

Comment: So i tried the method you recommended but all my Time column takes on the form of only 1 date and time '2015-09-28 12:49:43:920'  and it repeats all the way to the bottom for 280 rows :)...

Comment: @Navoneel just forgot to cast YourColumn as date too. SELECT * FROM Throuhput WHERE CAST(YourColumn AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)

Comment: what's the type of Time column?

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thanks people.

Comment: @MatBailie that isn't true. Casting a datetime to a date is one of those rare times a function around a column IS SARGable. There are plenty of articles and discussions on this. Here is a connect item on the topic. https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/526431/make-more-functions-sargable

Answer (score 1):

If your time column is of type datetime then this simple where will work

```
select * from throughput
where time = cast(cast(GetDate() as Date) as datetime)
```

If time column isn't of type datetime then you need to cast it to date as well and use the following query

```
select *,cast(GetDate() as Date) from throughput
where cast(time as date) = cast(GetDate() as Date)
```

I have created a fiddle to demonstrate both of the scenario

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce980/1)**